# download button should behave like below as based on condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a situation like below :
button with fixed place with name as Download, Here using post API for Download

condition one : when payload length becomes greater then 0 it should directly Download the file.

condition two : same button when payload length exactly becomes 0 needs to open the modal and in the modal if user clicked on continue to Download then it should Download file.

I have tried like below :

```
Button code :
    <button
         id="download-data"
          title= "download"
          (click)="exportToZip(false)"
          role="button">
            download
    </button>

Modal code :
     <ibm-modal [open]="isExportModalButtonEnabled">
            <ibm-modal-header (closeSelect)="closeModal()">
              <h4 id="modal-header" ibmModalHeaderHeading>
                {{ 'Download' | translate }}
              </h4>
            </ibm-modal-header>
            <ibm-modal-footer id="modal-footer">
              <ng-container>
                <button class="cancel-button" (click)="closeModal()">
                  {{ 'cancelButton' | translate }}
                </button>
                <button (click)="exportToZip(true)">
                  {{ continueToDownload | translate }}
                </button>
              </ng-container>
            </ibm-modal-footer>
          </ibm-modal>
```

.ts code :

```
exportToZip(shouldShowModal : boolean) {
    const {
      technicalServiceFilterList,
    } = this.getQueryParams();
    const exportParams = {
      technicalServiceFilterList,
      period : "latest",
    };
    const payload = technicalServiceFilterList.length?technicalServiceFilterList.split(','): [];
console.log(payload.length, "Length")
      if (payload.length === 0 && shouldShowModal) {
        this.isExportModalButtonEnabled = true;

   //subscribe code       this.ManagementService.downloadDetails(exportParams,payload).subscribe((response) => {
            this.downloadZip(response, selectedRow);
          });

      } else if((payload.length > 0 && shouldShowModal === false)) {
        this.isExportModalButtonEnabled = false;

          //subscribe code       this.ManagementService.downloadDetails(exportParams,payload).subscribe((response) => {
            this.downloadZip(response, selectedRow);
          });
      }
  }
```

Note : when length is 0 means  modal should open and user clicks on continue to download then only download.

Comment: What is the behavior you are getting? Since you are statically passing false in shouldShowModal the popup is never supposed to open

Comment: I am not getting modal in opened state.

Comment: 1. (click)="exportToZip(false)"
2. if (payload.length === 0 && shouldShowModal)
3. else if((payload.length > 0 && shouldShowModal === false))

Since in 1 you are passing shouldShowModal as false the condition mentioned in the 2 will always be false. So the modal will never open. I am not understanding why this variable shouldShowModal is needed we can simply do

1. (click)="exportToZip()"
2. if (payload.length === 0)
3. else if(payload.length > 0)